# Special handling of multiple urls to one view with class based generic views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am converting a WordPress site to a django one.  I need to preserve the url structure for old posts, but have a different structure for new posts.  I've done this by creating the 2 urls, setting a date in settings.py, then setting the absolute url like so:

urls.py

```
url(r'^reviews/archives/(?P<pk>\d+)$', PostDetail.as_view(), name="oldpost_view"),
```

posts/urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', PostDetail.as_view(), name="post_view"),
```

posts/models.py

```
@property        
def is_old_post(self):
    wp_date = settings.WP_ARCHIVE_DATE
    if self.post_date.date() < wp_date:
        return True
    # return False

@models.permalink    
def get_abs_url(self):
    if self.is_old_post:
        return ('oldpost_view', (), {
            'pk': self.id,
            }
        )
    else:
        return ('post_view', [str(self.url_slug)])
```

I am using one view for the 2 urls:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    slug_field = 'url_slug'
    template_name = "posts/detail.html"
```

This all works great.  Now, what I need to is prevent new posts from being rendered by the oldpost_view url and vice versa.  I know I can override the "get" and use reverse for this but how can I tell which url the request came from?  What is the most efficient and DRY way to do this?

Comment: first, you say that your urls are linked to the same view, and then you say that different kinds of urls should be rendered by different views. so the answer is apparent. Just handle them by different views.

Comment: What you really want to do is have a permanaent redirect from the old ones to the new ones. You don't want two URLs for the same content. If you do permanent redirects (301 status code) almost every client will recognize that.

Comment: +several million for Issac's comment.

Comment: I thought Isaac's ideas was brilliant and I felt bad I didn't remember that so I started working on it.  Getting into it I remembered though that only new posts will have slugs so I can't permanently redirect old posts to the new url unless I can somehow create slugs for all the old posts.  Hmm.

Comment: Actually, it turns out WordPress already has a slug field called "post_name".  That is awesome.  I'll work on the redirect and report back.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Issac Kelly's feedback I was able to solve my problem.  Here's the updated views:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    slug_field = 'post_name'
    template_name = "posts/detail.html"

def OldPostView(request, pk):
    post_name = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk).post_name
    return redirect('post_view', slug=post_name, permanent=True)
```

I also updated my models to utilize the "post_name" field that WordPress has, then simplified my permalink:

```
@models.permalink    
def get_abs_url(self):
    return ('post_view', [str(self.post_name)])
```

Thanks Issac!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't follow my advice with the '301' status code above, here is how I would do it:

1. Override the get method on the DetailView
2. If the date is before CUTOFF_DATE, and request.path[:10] != "reviews/arc" --> Redirect (301)
3. elseif date is after CUTOFF_DATE and request.path[:10] == "reviews/arc" --> redirect

Something roughly like that.